# Unable to pass the values into the password field in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to pass the text into password field but I can able find the password field.
Below is my selenium code:

```
 WebElement wb2=getDriver().findElement(By.name("txtFakePassword"));
 wb2.sendKeys("2323");
```

wb2 element is able to find the location, when passing(`wb2.sendKeys("2323")`) password it is placing there. And I did not get any error.

Please help me on this ###TIA####

This is my HTML code:

```
    <td id="txtFakePassword_CC" class="">
        <input tabindex="2" class="dxeTextBoxSys formField" name="txtFakePassword" 
        onkeyup="aspxEKeyUp('txtFakePassword', event)"
        value="PASSWORD" maxlength="20" id="txtFakePassword" 
        onchange="aspxEValueChanged('txtFakePassword')" 
        onblur="aspxELostFocus('txtFakePassword')" 
        onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('txtFakePassword')"
        type="text" autocomplete="off">

        <input type="hidden" name="txtFakePassword$CVS" value="-Password is required.">
    </td>
```

Comment: its type is hidden, that may be the problem

Comment: If it is not giving you error , then are you able to log in??

Comment: Issue was resolved. The problem was after clicking the password txt field the id got dynamically changed to "txtPassword". So First I click the password element using id "txtFakePassword" and then I pass the values using id "txtPassword"...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to  execute a js script to change the status of the element:

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...your element"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('type', '  ')", element);
```

Then try to pass your password to the new input showed